# sharepoint online taxonomy cascading dropdown

Tags: taxonomy, cascadingdropdown, sharepoint-online

I have a custom filter webpart to which i want to add cascading drop down selection. I need the drop downs to populate using the parent and child nodes of the termset.

example term set hierarchy:

Country>>states>>cities

so my question is.. how can i use the termstore to populate 3 dropdowns and have them cascade based on the given hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

Try using SP services for the managed metadata field.

they have functions to get the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but maybe someone came across this and needs answers.

I found a Solution for this problem. It is called Branding.JSLink and you can find it on [Github](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Branding.JSLink)

I also found a blogpost where Github's solution has been adapted for multiple taxonomy fields.

[Multivalue Taxonomy Field](https://www.smarterbusiness.at/en/sharepoint-multiple-selection-taxonomy-field-as-dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

Like Stefan said, answering an old post in case it helps someone.

Hope [this newly contributed PnP sample](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-graph-cascading-managed-metadata) addresses the requirement in the question for modern SharePoint.

For classic SharePoint, please refer [this blog article](https://medium.com/@anoopt/cascading-managed-metadata-9191fd50a6f8).